# Не получается запустить RTC на STM32F407

Tags: stm32

Пытаюсь запустить RTC периферию на МК STM32F407. 
Такты есть, флаги устанавливаются, но часы не тикают.
Код

```
RCC->CSR |= RCC_CSR_LSION;  
while (!(RCC->CSR & RCC_CSR_LSIRDY));

RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_PWREN;
PWR->CR |= PWR_CR_DBP;

RCC->BDCR |= RCC_BDCR_BDRST;
__NOP;
RCC->BDCR &=~ RCC_BDCR_BDRST;

RCC->BDCR |= RCC_BDCR_RTCEN | RCC_BDCR_RTCSEL_1;

RTC->WPR = 0xCA;
__NOP();
__NOP();
__NOP();
RTC->WPR = 0x53;
__NOP();
__NOP();
__NOP();

RTC->ISR |= RTC_ISR_INIT;
while (!(RTC->ISR & RTC_ISR_INITF));

RTC->TR = 0x194000;
RTC->DR = 0x198124;

while (1){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calendar initialization and configuration

...

5. Exit the initialization mode by clearing the INIT bit. The actual calendar counter value is then automatically loaded and the counting restarts after 4 RTCCLK clock cycles.

When the initialization sequence is complete, the calendar starts counting.